# Condition on value for style on Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, styles, conditional-statements

I'd like to check the value of my template

```
        <template slot="projected_end_date" slot-scope="{ line }">
            <datetime-display :value="line.projected_end_date"
                              type="date"
            style= "color: red"></datetime-display>
         </template>
```

and only set the style for red color when my value is less than current date. Any suggestion? I'm assuming it should be something like

```
value > DateHelper.now()? style = ...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [Class and Styles Bindings](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html)

You can use it like:

```
<div :class="{'my-class': myCondition}">
```

Simple example

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selectedColor: 'red'
  }
})
```

```css
.red { background: red}
.blue { background: blue}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="selectedColor='red'">Red</button>
  <button @click="selectedColor='blue'">Blue</button>
  <p :class="{red: selectedColor === 'red', blue: selectedColor === 'blue'}">the background color will change !</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [class and style binding](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) like this:

```
:style="value < DateHelper.now() ? { 'color': 'red'} : ''"
```

Or,

```
:style="{color: value < DateHelper.now() ? 'red' : 'inherit'}"
```

Or some default color:

```
:style="{color: value < DateHelper.now() ? 'red' : 'black'}"
```

---

But I suggest you to use class binding whenever possible:

```
:class="{warning: value < DateHelper.now()}"
```

And in your css styles:

```
.warning {
   color: red;
}
```

Also, you can simply use [Date.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) instead of a helper function.